Check deleted folder in GCP bucket
I use this code to read files from GCP bucket:
if len(input_dir)>0:
    logger.info(f'Fetching GCS data for prefix:{input_dir}')
    gcs_prefix = input_dir.split(f'{bucket.name}/')[-1]
    metadata_files = []
    metadata_prefix = f"{gcs_prefix}Metadata/"
    csv_df = pd.DataFrame()
    for blob in storage_client.list_blobs(bucket.name, prefix=metadata_prefix):
        if blob.name.rsplit('.', 1)[-1].lower().strip() in EXTN_CSV:
            metadata_files.append(f"gs://{BUCKET_NAME}/{blob.name}")
    meta_files_list = (pd.read_csv(file) for file in metadata_files)
    if not meta_files_list:
        # log exit and exit
        logger.error(f"### job Stopped because file is empty!")
        return empty_extract_df

    meta_files_df = pd.concat(meta_files_list)

When file is processed it should be moved/deleted. But I get error: ValueError("No objects to concatenate") ValueError: No objects to concatenate at this line: meta_files_df = pd.concat(meta_files_list)
I noticed that when the last file is deleted from folder Metadata/ the folder is also automatically deleted.
Ref: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/148487275
Possible solution that I can think of is to check also for Metadata/ and if it's not present to exit the job.
How I can implement this check?

try on ChatgptOverflow

There's nothing like folder in GCS. You need to read more about how it works https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/objects#namespace . Simply check if the list is returned at the prefix, if not then there's no such "folder"
